# DataRow Is Not Showing Up

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have used DataRow which could be displayed in a combobox in my WinForm but somehow, it is not working, although the entire table is successfully being displayed in the gridview.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=StudentDetails;Integrated Security=True";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from StuDet";
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just now figured out the answer, Please take a look at the loop at the bottom.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=StudentDetails;Integrated Security=True";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from studet";
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dr[0] = dt.Rows[i][0];
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You create an empty new row

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
```

and add it `Rows.Count` times to `comboBox1`. I think what you want is to go through each row in `dt.Rows`:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["Roll"]);
}
```

Comment: Can I use a "for loop" instead of foreach?

Comment: a) yes you can but you need to get the row in your loop `DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i]` b) what's wrong with `foreach`?

Comment: I am a student which is why I am trying to experiment with all sorts of things. I could have simply worked my way around a DataTable and got the combo box populated but still i chose to work with DataRow for learning a few concepts. If you find my answer useful, plz vote me up.